# Python Fabric perform remote database task

Tags: python, postgresql, ssh, ubuntu-14.04, fabric

I need to ssh to a remote Ubuntu server to do some routine job, in following steps:

1. ssh in as userA
2. sudo su - userB
3. run daliy_python.py script with use psycopg2 to read some info from the database (via local connection (non-TCP/IP))
4. scp readings to my local machine

The question is: How to do that automatically?
I've try to use Fabric, but I run into a problem with psycopg2, after I run the Fabric script below, I received error from my daliy_python.py

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/xxx/.s.xxxx"?
```

My fabfile.py code is as below:

```
from fabric.api import *

import os
import socket
import pwd

# Target machine setting
srv = 'server.hostname.com'
env.hosts = [srv]
env.user = 'userA'
env.key_filename = '/location/to/my/key'

env.timeout = 2
# Force fabric abort at timeout
env.skip_bad_hosts = False

def run_remote():
    user = 'userB'    
    with settings(warn_only=True):
        run('whoami')
        with cd('/home/%s/script/script_folder' % user):
            sudo('whoami')
            sudo('pwd', user=user)
            sudo('ls', user=user)
            sudo('python daliy_python.py', user=user)
```

Any suggestions? My database can only be access via userB locally, but only userA can ssh to the server. That might be a limitation. Both local and remote machine is running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: That's a database connection error which is really a separate concern from running remote processes with fabric.  See some of these possible solutions: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500332/cant-connect-the-postgresql-with-psycopg2
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26034092/connection-error-while-connecting-to-postgresql-as-postgres-user

Comment: @chishaku Thanks, I don't know where this error comes from, If I am ssh to the server and perform the job, it works fine. It just happened when I use fabric script, that makes me wonder if I did something wrong with the fabric setting/or I should use other tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find out where my problem is.
Thanks @chishake and @C14L, I look at the problem in another way.
After inspired by this posts [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13801188/4627539) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13080643), I start to think this problem is related to environmental variables.
Thus I add a with statement to alter $HOME and it worked.

fabfile.py is as below:

```
from fabric.api import *

import os
import socket
import pwd

# Target machine setting
srv = 'server.hostname.com'
env.hosts = [srv]
env.user = 'userA'
env.key_filename = '/location/to/my/key'

env.timeout = 2
# Force fabric abort at timeout
env.skip_bad_hosts = False

def run_remote():
    user = 'userB'    
    with settings(warn_only=True):
        run('whoami')
        with shell_env(HOME='/home/%s' % user):
            sudo('echo $HOME', user=user)
            with cd('/home/%s/script/script_folder' % user):
                sudo('whoami')
                sudo('pwd', user=user)
                sudo('ls', user=user)
                sudo('python daliy_python.py', user=user)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do to read my root accessible logfiles without extra login

```
ssh usera@12.34.56.78 "echo hunter2 | sudo -S tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log"
```

That is: `ssh usera@12.34.56.78 "..run this code on the remote.."`

Then on the remote, you pipe the sudo password into `sudo -S` `echo hunter2 | sudo -S`

Add a `-u userb` to sudo to switch to a particular user, I am using root in my case. So then as the sudo'ed user, run your script. In my case `tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log`.

But, reading your post, I would probably simply set up a cronjob on the remote, so it runs automatically. I actually do that for all my databases. A cronjob dumps them once a day to a certain directory, with the date as filename. Then I download them to my local PC with rsync an hour later.

Comment: Thanks, possibly it is the better option. To do it in to two steps, one, cron job running on server, dump new info to a file, second, ssh to the server and download the file.